# Java keyboard hook

Tags: java, keyboard, mouse

I would like to write a Java app that counts how long I have been using the keyboard or mouse w/o a break. Are there any built-in classes or 3rd party libraries that can detect global keyboard/mouse use?

Comment: When I type on the keyboard, sometimes I take short pauses to either think about what I am about to type or scratch my nose :) What would you describe as a break? More than a minute unresponsive to keystrokes?

Comment: In case you want to replicate the effect, and not the fun of writing it yourself, have you looked at WorkRave? (www.workrave.org)

Comment: @Anthony: of course the break interval should be configurable. @Alex: thanks! I might just use that instead if it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

This can only be by using windows's hook function by JNI
Someone already posted code [here](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=632369)

EDIT: this on is better it also covers [mouse events](http://www.jotschi.de/?p=90)

Answer (score 0):

The collection of files for **[rawinputsharp](http://www.jstookey.com/arcade/rawmouse/)** and the accompanying article might prove helpful. It's not Java-specific, but hopefully you can adapt it to suit.